# Reading and posting the values from a multidimensional array

Tags: jquery

I am creating a quiz using jQuery. I know that this is not a incredibly difficult task but I seem to be running into issues with the following:
(a)reading in the values of the multi-dimensional array, i.e. the answers to the question which is the element[0] of the array
AND
(b)presenting those values after the radio buttons which appear in my html.

Here's what I have in the HTML

```
       <!--practice quiz-->
    <div id="practiceQuestions">

   <div class="questionBox">
  <div class="theQuestion">
  <span id="quizQuestion"><img src="images/Practice_Tips_Math.png"></span>
  <INPUT type="submit" value="Start quiz now" id="startQuiz" class="viewable">

    <!--answer key beginsb-->

    <div class="answerBox">
      <form name="answerForm">
        <input type="radio" value="a" id="answerA" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="b" id="answerB" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="c" id="answerC" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="d" id="answerD" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="e" id="answerE" name="quizAnswer"><br /> 
      </form></div>
      <!--answer key end-->

  </div>

 </div> 



</div>
<!--practice quiz ends-->
```

And here's what I have in the jQuery

```
var question=[
['How many moons does Earth have?',1,2,3,4,5],
['How many moons does Saturn have?',31,32,33,34,35],
['How many moons does Venus have?', 0,1,2,3,4]
];

function askQuestion(question){
if($('#startQuiz').is(':visible')) {
    $('#startQuiz').toggle();
    }
if($('.answerBox').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.answerBox').toggle();
    $('.answerBox').css('margin-top','50px');

    }
    $(".theQuestion").css('margin-top','75px');
    $("#quizQuestion").text(question[0]);
//want the answers from question array to appear here from question[i]
        $('#answerA').text(question[1]);
$('#answerB').text(question[2]);
$('#answerC').text(question[3]);
$('#answerD').text(question[4]);
$('#answerE').text(question[5]);
};

 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#startQuiz').on('click',function(){      
    for (var i=0; i<=question.length; i++)
        {
         askQuestion(question[i]);
        }
    }); 

 });
```

Comment: You have more issues. One would be to change to this: `$('#startQuiz').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault();` Another would be to ask one question at a time I think. Create a jsfiddle.net and ask one question at a time

Comment: The issue is that these are multidimensional arrays, as you stated. Given this fact, to access`'How many moons does the earth have?'` you would need to do: `question[0][0]`